# Day, Month, Year format in Excel Issues

Tags: excel

As part of my data analysis project in R this semester, I need to make a boxplot for the THY stock. I have a csv file that contains everything that I need to work with, however, I can't figure out why I can't tidy this up a little nicer in Excel before importing to R. I've tried the basic wrangling/tidying stuff that I learned this semester, but I am at a loss.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish: [image: Excel Time Format]

I managed to build the Day, Month, and Year columns very easily using `=DAY(A2)`, `=MONTH(A2)`, and `=YEAR(A2)` commands.

However, with the new csv file I downloaded from Yahoo Finance, I get this: [image: The issue that I'm experiencing.]

I used the same commands, `=DAY(A2)` and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is the new csv like? (open in a text editor, not Excel) It looks like a date format/regional issue.

Comment: It looks "normal." It looks exactly the same in Notepad as it does in Excel. Also, when I formatted the "A" column as date and I still have the same issues.

Comment: Column B is formatted as a short date.  In Excel select the column and format it as a number.

Comment: @Dave2e, I did that, and that is what the issue was! Thank you so much for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your excel file I can't be certain, but I'm pretty sure you have a formatting issue.

Change the format of column B to 'General'.

Comment: LOL, now that you mention it it's quite evident... It's just day "1" displayed as date.

Comment: Bonus tip: take a little care manipulating a csv in excel that contains dates before importing into R. You might find that Excel 'helpfully' changes the date column format into month/day/year for you. In R you will want to ensure you coerce to a format that can be used with POSIX class for many functions. probably something like as.Date(x, format="%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: @Joe_P, you absolutely nailed it! Thanks for the info!